# How to kill all livestock?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, fauna

I have decided to join a new group, they call themselves Earthborn, they are like PETA in a way, but different. Their goal is to force vegetarianism on all humans, at any cost, in order to prevent world hunger. Our organization is a lot more agreed with, we have an estimated 41 million members, all willing to put their lives (and more importantly their wallets) on the line. Current counts suggest that we have about 800 million dollars in liquid assets.

Now, we aren't terrorists *technically*, but we do have a plan. We are going to kill **all** of the livestock on earth, from chickens to cows. But can we even do this? If we can, what is the most effective method of accomplishing such a task?

Unlike [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27268/how-would-radical-vegans-animal-rights-activists-kill-all-the-animals-to-preven), I only want to kill livestock, not all living animals

Comment: How serious are you?  The more you actually mean what you say when you say "**all** of the livestock," the more precisely we're going to have to define what livestock is.  As an example, some dogs are livestock in Korea.  What does that mean for dogs worldwide?

Comment: @CortAmmon widespread livestock only

Comment: @TrEs-2b So that's a pretty vague definition.  Does that mean you don't mind if we miss a few?

Comment: @TrE-2b if you killed all the current livestock spieces many ominvorous people would not stop eating meat. They would just find other food animals such as dogs in Korea, wild seafood, game birds, snails even small songbird such as larks are eaten in some parts of the world.

Comment: One thing I don't understand in this story is that you'd be wanting to force people to go vegetarian, but you kill all livestock, so you'd in fact force them to go vegan, right? Since vegetarians still eat dairy products, which would no longer be produced if all livestock is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given that you are looking at killing all livestock, i would suggest releasing low levels of a toxic chemical into the atmosphere, it would be toxic to smaller organisms (possibly children and asthmatics too) but if you were to warn everyone to wear gas masks then this could be relatively safe.

alternatively: neuter / spay all livestock, they cant breed, they die out after however many years (assuming scientists don't intervene)

OR: release diseases that are exclusive to a species (eg mad cow disease) which will drastically drop the numbers, but may not kill them all

## However

with all these schemes, if they become well known, then the genetics can be preserved and extreme measures can be taken to ensure they do not all die out, as it could be disastrous for the ecosystem

(P.S. please do not try these methods at home)